# Create automatic user password via Wordpress Api

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to create a user via the Wordpress restAPI however I need to use WP's wp_generate_password function to automatically create the password for the user. This is the code I'm using to create the user with a password via curl:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==" -X POST -d email=example_user@example.com -d username=example_user https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users
```

..but I obviously need to do this without the password parameter and have WP use its auto generate function. I'm not sure how to do this via the restAPI though. Reading online has led me to PHP only solutions which doesn't fit for my case here as this is from a mobile app. Any help is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: hey, did you ever find the answer? I'm in the same boat